# C# Instantiate Prefab with Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, instantiation

I have a little problem with this code:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canClick)
    {
        Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mouseWorldPosition.z = player.transform.position.z;
        directionVector = player.transform.position - mouseWorldPosition;
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionVector.normalized * speed);
        Quaternion InstanceRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseWorldPosition.x - 90f, 0f, 0f);
        GameObject effect = Instantiate(SteamFx, mouseWorldPosition, InstanceRotation);
        effect.transform.LookAt(directionVector);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when instantiating the object, it has a z rotation. So I have an effect that when I click on the screen, it should instantiate, and blow in the player direction. It has different rotation, how to make the rotation correct.
Thks!!!

Comment: What does the 3rd parameter of `Instantiate(SteamFx, mouseWorldPosition, Quaternion.identity);` mean? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html

Comment: I know what it means...

Comment: I've already done something that changed something, but it does not do this rotation depending on the code above

Comment: Thank you, I've already resolved :)))

Comment: If you solved by yourself is usually good practice post the answer because other people may have the same problem

Comment: @AlessioZapBoerio do *you* need an answer?

Comment: @yes no thanks, it was only a tip to keep stackoverflow clean